# Cannot read property 'string' of undefined | React.PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-proptypes

I installed the `prop-types` package by running `npm i prop-types --save` and my dependencies are:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


function Question(props) {
  return (
    <h2 className="question">{props.content}</h2>
  );
 }

 Question.propTypes = {
    content: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  export default Question;
```

I restarted node 5-6 times but still getting this error: 
      [image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a ReactJS documentation/tutorial page, [*Type Checking with PropTypes*](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), it looks like you are attempting to access `PropTypes` using the old approach.

Try using this instead:

```
Question.propTypes = {
    content: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) you don't need the `React` prefix:

```
Question.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```